# Python: una lista que esta dentro de varias listas

Tags: python

Al recorrer el código obtengo:

```
[[[['j']]]]
[[['j']]]
[['j']]
['j']
```

Quiero estandarizar el código para que sirva si tengo 5 corchetes, 6 corchetes o más. Y vaya desagregando como muestro en el ejemplo. Atenta a sus comentarios

```
k=[[[[['j']]]]]
n=0
while n<4:
    for k in k:
        print(k)
    n=n+1
```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask] o hacerlo nuevamente en caso de haberlo hecho con anterioridad. En este sitio no resolvemos tareas y/o proyectos. Para cada pregunta es necesario que agregues un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que podamos ayudarte. Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código que has intentado utilizar.

Comment: En ningún momento mi intención es que me hagan código. Ya lo edite, solo que no se estandarizarlo, ya no veo.

Comment: Gracias por editar la pregunta, siempre es importante mostrar el esfuerzo para que podamos ayudarte, las preguntas que no incluyen código por lo general son cerradas y/o votadas negativamente ya que evitamos fomentar la holgazanería y además va en contra de las normas del sitio. Ahora reviso tu duda.

Comment: Gracias, de verdad aprecio tu comentario

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

En `Python` una forma fácil de desempaquetar una lista es utilizando el operador asterisco ([Lectura recomendada](https://es.acervolima.com/python-operador-de-estrella-o-asterisco/#:%7E:text=Se%20utiliza%20para%20pasar%20un,de%20argumentos%20de%20longitud%20variable.)). Que permite acceder a los elementos internos de una lista (Entre otras cosas), por ejemplo:

```
arr = ['domingo', 'lunes', 'martes', 'miercoles']
print (*arr)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
domingo lunes martes miercoles
```

Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar un `while` que se ejecute continuamente hasta que lo que contenga `k` no sea una lista.

Para evaluar si lo que contiene `k` es una lista o no podemos utilizar [`isinstance()`](https://interactivechaos.com/es/python/function/isinstance)

Ejemplo completo:

```
k = [[[[['j']]]]]

while isinstance(*k, list):
    for k in k:
        print(k)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
[[[['j']]]]
[[['j']]]
[['j']]
['j']
```

Y si lo ejecutamos con una lista de listas con un nivel de profundidad más grande, por ejemplo `k = [[[[[[[['j']]]]]]]]`:

```
[[[[[[['j']]]]]]]
[[[[[['j']]]]]]
[[[[['j']]]]]
[[[['j']]]]
[[['j']]]
[['j']]
['j']
```